How to solve "TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" in PyTorch CNN architecture
I am using MNIST to train a CNN using the following code:
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


train_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    download=True
    )

test_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    download=True
    )

# Process data to batches
loaders = {
    "train": DataLoader(train_data,
                        batch_size=100,
                        shuffle=True,
                        num_workers=0),

    "test": DataLoader(test_data,
                       batch_size=100,
                       shuffle=True,
                       num_workers=0)
}

class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x), 2)))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return F.softmax(x)
    

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = CNN().to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                       lr=0.001)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


def train(epoch):

    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(loaders["train"]):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 20 == 0:
            print(f'Train epoch: {epoch} [{batch_idx * len(data)}/{len(loaders["train"].dataset)} ({100. * batch_idx / len(loaders["train"]):.0f}%)]\t{loss.item():.6f}')


def test():
    model.eval()

    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in loaders["test"]:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += loss_fn(output, target).item()
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(loaders['test'].dataset)
    print(f'\nTest set: Average loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {correct}/{len(loaders["test"].dataset)} ({100. * correct / len(loaders["test"].dataset):.0f}%\n)')


for epoch in range(1, 11):
    train(epoch)
    test()


But when executing this, I get the following stacktrace of errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/u/Projects/venv/src/digits_model_training.py", line 103, in <module>
    train(epoch)
  File "c:/Users/u/Projects/venv/src/digits_model_training.py", line 76, in train
    output = model(data)
  File "C:\Users\u\Projects\venv\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u\Projects\venv\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/u/Projects/venv/src/digits_model_training.py", line 51, in forward
    x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x), 2)))
  File "C:\Users\u\Projects\venv\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u\Projects\venv\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I have only passed x, which is the image, to the forward() function. Therefore I am surprised by the error. The error, however, seems to be pretty common (e.g. see here or here) and can have a variety of underlying reasons. Mostly it is because people have passed multiple arguments. But I haven't, at least not conciously. One notice, although it is most probably completely unrelated to the error: I do not have a NVIDIA GPU, which is why in my case, device=torch.device('cpu').
Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

There seems to be an error in the forward function at x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x), 2))). Here, the dropout layer is being called with two arguments, (output of conv layer and 2) due to misuse of parenthesis.
Here's the corrected version:
class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        # the line below is wrong in the original code
        # Dropout layer only takes one argument, wrong use of parenthesis make it two input arguments
        # x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x), 2))) 
        
        # correct line
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return F.softmax(x)


Well observed, thank you!
